# Не отображается задний фон

Tags: html, css, django, веб-программирование

Не подгружается картинка заднего фона, которая прописана в файле css.
Сам css файл подгружается.

HTML:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title> New registration </title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{% static 'css_styles/register.css' %}" />
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #ffffff url('../image/daac3.png') no-repeat center top ;
}
```

Так же пробовал в файле указывать прямой путь к файлу. всё равно не отображается задний фон

Comment: А где располагается этот файл?

Comment: Попробуй прямо в хтмл подключить в блоке <style>...</style>. С `!important`. При условии, что правильно путь указали, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем css-свойстве `background` всё написано правильно, поэтому здесь могут быть 2 причины:

- вы прописали неверный путь до изображения, проверьте также расширение файла,
- значение данного свойства переопределяется в другом месте, проверьте это через "Инспектор DOM" (<kbd>F12</kbd> в браузере).

Answer (score 0):

Напишите вот так:

```
background: #ffffff url('/image/daac3.png') no-repeat center top ;
```