# Background-image не работает, не подгружает картику

Tags: html, css

Здраствуйте, не прогружает картинку:(

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #333;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
margin: 0%;
}

/*container*/

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

/*intro*/

.intro {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

    background: 
    url("/assets/images/intro.jpg") center 
    no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html leng="eng"> 
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script|Montserrat:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
       <title>Mogo</title>
       </head>
    <body>
       <div class="intro">
            <div class="container">
            <h1>Mogo</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Только эту или все?

Comment: Только эту картинку

Comment: Может быть выводит какие-то ошибки в консоли разработчика?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не отображается задний фон](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1000504/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас папки css и images находятся на одном уровне.
Попробуйте указать следующий путь к файлу:

```
 background: url("../images/intro.jpg") center no-repeat;
```

Т.е.написав ../ вы выходите из текущей папки (в нашем случае из папки css) и заходите в папку images, в которой и обращаетесь к изображению intro.jpg

Comment: путь у автора указан с корня `/`. и с чего вы взяли что на одном уровне?

Comment: Автор указал в файле style.css путь к изображению background:   url("/assets/images/intro.jpg") center no-repeat. Делаю вывод, что папка images находится в папке assets. В файле index.html автор подключает стили    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">.  Т.е папка css также находится в папке assets.  Выходит, что папки css и images находятся на одном уровне

Answer (score 0):

У вас в папке нету картинки значит или вы указали неправильный путь. Добавил первую попавшееся фото в класс intro и все работает.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #333;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
margin: 0%;
}

/*container*/

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

/*intro*/

.intro {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

    background: 
    url("https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2019/07/19/20/20190719202701230/top7_7b989314a6df4679cdf0a6538036e872.jpg") center 
    no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html leng="eng"> 
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script|Montserrat:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
       <title>Mogo</title>
       </head>
    <body>
       <div class="intro">
            <div class="container">
            <h1>Mogo</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```